# ng: command not found after system update

Tags: node.js, macos, angular

I'm on macOS Sierra and after system update angular-cli has an issue where I can no longer run ng commands.  I did some research and the common cause seems to be a path issue which I tried to resolve using the following steps:

1. `npm install -g angular@latest`
2. Make sure the ng path is correct

   - `cd ~/npm-global/bin`
   - `ls and make sure ng exists`
3. create .bashrc file on your home directory

   - `touch ~/.bashrc`
   - `vim ~/.bashrc`
4. Add ng as alias

   - press a (enables edit mode) then type in the following
   - `alias ng="~/npm-global/bin/ng"`
   - press esc (to get out of edit mode) then `:wq` (in vim will save)
5. Restart terminal
6. Check that ng works

   - `ng --version`

The above did not work, however.  I also found an odd issue while following these steps. When I  `cd ~/npm-global/bin` I see the ng directory, when when I try to `cd ng` it said no such directory exists.  Is this related to the problem?  My node version is v6.9.4.

I have tried every solution I have come across but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that npm was not pathed when I checked `echo $PATH`

If this is your issue do the following:

1) `touch ~/.bash_profile`

2) `open ~/.bash_profile`

3) `export PATH="/Users/<your home directory>/npm/bin:$PATH"`

4) `restart terminal`

5) `ng --version` (to verify)